# Using SharedPreferences in Activity

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am absolutely new to java programming and android. I have a simple question and hope I do not need a code for that.

I create an android app in andoroid studio. I have a second activity which contains a list view.

My java's are MainActivity - secondActivity - myAdapter. My Layout's are listview_item - activity_main - activity_detail(secondActivity).

**My question:** If I want to use a `SharedPreferences` function in my `detail_activity` layout. Where to put this code?

- secondActivity
- MainActivity
- Create a new class

I was searching for answers but I didn't find anything.

Thank you!

Comment: SharedPreferences is for saving key-value paired data, if you want to save data then you can use it in any activity

Comment: what do you want to sore in store in `SharedPreference`

Comment: @Shubham Vala, I have 5 differen't text edit for simple numbers (like 55538 not more then 6 digits). I just wan't to save them and have them back after starting the app.

Answer (score 1):

Shared Preferences saved data as a `<K,V>` pair.

I think you should understand how Shared Pref work... if you did you wouldn't really be able to answer your own question.

Where ever you want to save data, that is where you call shared pref.

To save Data:

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("key", "value");
editor.commit();
```

To get this...

```
sharedpreferences.getString("key", null); // getting string (null is the default value)
editor.commit();
```

To remove...

```
editor.remove("key"); // will remove key from shared pref
editor.commit();
```

To clear ALL...

```
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

So, if you want to save data before going into the new activity, you save it to your prefs, then you load it from your prefs in the new activity. If you delete, then you call the `.remove()` method to remove it in that activity.

Also, it is also important not to store everything in your shared pref.
Only store things that you will use often, but also use a database to keep everything aligned. Do not think a shared pref system is a database, its not, and do not use it as such.

Hopefully this makes it more straight forward.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use SharedPreferences in second activity so you can put your code in second activity. It will be easy for you.